# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported data type NullType when turning a dataframe into permanent hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie in spark . I have created a data frame by using sql query inside pyspark. i want to make it as permanent table  for getting advantage in future work. i used  bellow code

```
spark.sql("select b.ENTITYID as ENTITYID, cm.BLDGID as BldgID,cm.LEASID as LeaseID,coalesce(l.SUITID,(select EmptyDefault from EmptyDefault)) as SuiteID,(select CurrDate from CurrDate) as TxnDate,cm.INCCAT as IncomeCat,'??' as SourceCode,(Select CurrPeriod from CurrPeriod)as Period,coalesce(case when cm.DEPARTMENT ='@' then 'null' else cm.DEPARTMENT end, null) as Dept,'Lease' as ActualProjected ,fnGetChargeInd(cm.EFFDATE,cm.FRQUENCY,cm.BEGMONTH,(select CurrPeriod from CurrPeriod))*coalesce (cm.AMOUNT,0) as  ChargeAmt,0 as OpenAmt,null as Invoice,cm.CURRCODE as CurrencyCode,case when ('PERIOD.DATACLSD') is null then 'Open' else 'Closed' end as GLClosedStatus,'Unposted'as GLPostedStatus ,'Unpaid' as PaidStatus,cm.FRQUENCY as Frequency,0 as RetroPD from CMRECC cm join BLDG b on cm.BLDGID =b.BLDGID join LEAS l on cm.BLDGID =l.BLDGID and cm.LEASID =l.LEASID and (l.VACATE is null or l.VACATE >= ('select CurrDate from CurrDate')) and (l.EXPIR >= ('select CurrDate from CurrDate') or l.EXPIR < ('select RunDate from RunDate')) left outer join PERIOD on b.ENTITYID =  PERIOD.ENTITYID and ('select CurrPeriod from CurrPeriod')=PERIOD.PERIOD where ('select CurrDate from CurrDate')>=cm.EFFDATE  and (select CurrDate from CurrDate) <= coalesce(cm.EFFDATE,cast(date_add(( select min(cm2.EFFDATE) from CMRECC cm2 where cm2.BLDGID = cm.BLDGID and cm2.LEASID = cm.LEASID and cm2.INCCAT = cm.INCCAT and 'cm2.EFFDATE' > 'cm.EFFDATE'),-1) as timestamp)  ,case when l.EXPIR <(select RunDate from RunDate)then (Select RunDate from RunDate) else l.EXPIR end)").write.saveAsTable('FactChargeTempTable')
```

for making  permanent table but i am getting this error

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 11 in stage 73.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 11.0 in stage 73.0 (TID 2464, localhost): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported data type NullType.
```

I hav no idea why it is happening  and how could i solve it . Kindly guide 
me 
Thank you 
kalyan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error you have `Unsupported data type NullType` indicates that one of the columns for the table you are saving has a NULL column.  To workaround this issue, you can do a NULL check for the columns in your table and ensure that one of the columns isn't all NULL.

Note, if there is just one row within a column mostly of NULLs, Spark usually is able to identify the datatype (e.g. StringType, IntegerType, etc.) instead of the datatype of NullType.

Comment: hey in my case i had done `val df5 = df4.na.fill("-").na.fill(0).na.fill(false).na.fill(0.0).na.fill(Map[String, Any]())` meaning i replaced all null values with some default values. Now when we write the dataframe ; i still get `Unsupported data type NullType` ; infact i had printed the dataframe `df5` and every column had the default value in it. THen i am wondering what could be the reason for the `Exception` any thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

I have met this error when I run a spark-sql application.
You can cast `NULL` to String in first, like this:

```
lit(null).cast("string").
```

Answer (score 2):

@Denny Lee is correct. Someone did opened a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10943) for your issue and got similar response. One of the comment suggest the below way around:

Michael:Yeah, parquet doesn't have a concept of null type. I'd probably suggest they case null to a type CAST(NULL AS INT) if they really want to do this, but really you should just omit the column probably.

Comment: just FYI, it seems that the null type should be supported for Parquet files, however Spark has not caught up with it yet.

https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/LogicalTypes.md#null

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error too. All values in a specific column in my table was null and I was doing the below:
Select
null as column_name

I fixed it just by ‘not selecting’ that column at all.
If you don’t select that column in your final select it will be populated as null anyway without throwing this error.